# Dart non-async function return wait until for loop is complete

Tags: flutter, dart

Here is my code

```
List<DocumentReference> getStacks(
    List<DocumentReference> favoritePlayers,
    List<DocumentReference> stacks,
    ) {
  List<DocumentReference> newStacks = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < stacks.length; i++) {
    stacks[i].get().then((DocumentSnapshot stackSnapshot) {
      if (stackSnapshot.exists) {
        DocumentReference thisstack = stackSnapshot['player'];
        for (var x = 0; x < favoritePlayers.length; x++) {
          if (favoritePlayers[x] == thisstack) {
            newStacks.add(stacks[i]);
          }
        }
      }
    });
    if (stacks.length - 1 == i) {
      return newStacks;
    }
  }

}
```

I do not have the option in the platform I am using to make the function async or Future, so I am trying to figure out a way to not return until both for loops are done.  I have tried while loops and do while, but I guess I am missing something, this method is close, but it seems it still finishes before the inner loop does and wants to return nothing.

Any thoughts would be great.

Comment: what you are trying to do is not possible: you cannot "block" your method in any way, you have to use `Future` somehow

Comment: You're asking how to make an asynchronous function synchronous, which is not possible.  Any function that calls an asynchronous function and must wait for it to complete also becomes inherently asynchronous and therefore must return a `Future` too.

Comment: Your platform seems to be perfectly capable of supporting `Future`, given that you are *using it* in your code. The `.then()` kinda gives it away.

Comment: The problem is the constructor is prebuilt and can not be modified, I can add code to it, but I can not make it return a Future or make it async.  Thought might be a way in the function, but I guess its not.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the loop goes to the next operation without waiting for "stacks[i].get()" .

If the "stacks[i].get()" function is not a Future function, you can use it as follows.

```
List getStacks( List favoritePlayers, List stacks) {
   List newStacks = [];

   for (final stack in stacks) {
      DocumentSnapshot stackSnapshot = stack.get();
      //code
      newStacks.add(stackSnapshot);
   }

   return newStacks;
}
```

If it is a future function, it should be like this;

```
Future<List> getStacks( List favoritePlayers, List stacks) async{
   List newStacks = [];

   for (final stack in stacks) {
      DocumentSnapshot stackSnapshot = await stack.get();
      //code
      newStacks.add(stackSnapshot);
   }

   return newStacks;
}
```

Comment: The .get() is a future, its firebase.  I think the biggest problem is that it goes to the return before the inner loop finishes processing.